# import googlecheckstyle.xml to IntelliJ without using a plugin

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

Just modified a google-checkstyle.xml for my purpose and want to get it run without using a plugin etc.. Just my written file, imported in Settings --> Code Style --> Java --> Scheme

But there comes up an error message:

> IntelliJ IDEA code style XML import failed with error message: The
> file doesn't seem to be a valid Intellij IDEA XML scheme, it should
> contain 'code_scheme root' element, found 'module' instead.

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does not support google checkstyle XML format. See https://checkstyle.org/idea.html on how to use it with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: thank you very much, solved ist! Solved it via Checkstyle-Plugin.

Comment: do you have a tip for following situation: I do a check via the Maven-Plugin everything is fine, I compile the code, everything is good, but if I push the commits the structure of the files is changed, files are deleted and insert into other directories

Comment: it says "delete mode 100644 <...>" I never said that something has to be removed